# How to remove repeating characters from a text sentence?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a list of text sentences and there are many words such as aaaaa, zzzzz, eeer, qqqqqqq...

I am looking for a way to remove these from my text sentence.

```
text = I'm a really good aaaaaa eeeeer jjjjj llll bb
```

I couldn't figure out what regex I could use so I can remove these words completely. There are some edge cases like

```
1) aaaaae (you will have one another character at the end)
2) brrrrrr (another character at the beginning)
```

I'm looking for a output like this,

```
text = I'm really good
```

I just couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: There are various ways to detect a "word" that is all one letter.  One way is to make a set of the letters, check its length, and check the original word to see whether it's valid on its own.  You haven't detailed your boundary criteria enough for a clear solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'\s\b(\S)\1+\S*','',text)

"I'm a really good"
```

Edit: From the comment. It seems other words have a different pattern use:

```
 re.sub(r'\s\S*(.)(?:\1{2,}\S*|\1+\b\S*)','',text)
```

Comment: thanks a lot but It's not removing words like geeeee, reeeee where you have another character at the front.

Comment: @user_12 check the edit

Comment: I tried it on my text but it seems to be returning an error. error: unknown extension ?| at position 6. I'm using ipython notebook to test.

Comment: @user_12 Since this uses branch reset syntax, you would have to use `regex` instead of `re`. ie in your ipython notebook  do `!pip install regex` then `import regex` and lastly run `regex.sub(r'\s*\b(?|(\S)|.(\S))\1+\S*','',text)`

Comment: this seems to be removing words such as good, food... I only want to remove words such as `brrrrrrrrr, kkkke, zzzzzzz, rrrr, qq, p`...... words such as good,food are imp and I want them in my text.

Comment: @user_12 try the edit above useing `re`

Comment: @user_12 the one using thhe branch reset maintains good and food etc. I dont know why you get a different result

Answer (score 1):

`\b(?:\w(\w)\1+|(\w)\2+\w|(\w)\3+)\b`

https://regex101.com/r/iDVkRT/1

```
 \b 
 (?:
      \w 
      ( \w )                        # (1)
      \1+ 
   |  ( \w )                        # (2)
      \2+ \w 
   |  ( \w )                        # (3)
      \3+ 
 )
 \b
```

Comment: While this answer might be technically correct, it's always best to include a brief explanation along with the code to help new users (and the community in general) understand what the answer/code does.  Pure code does not help other 'learn' how/why the code works

Answer (score 1):

```
import re 

text = "I'm a really good aaaaaa eeeeer jjjjj llll bb"
out = re.sub(r"\w*(.)\1{3,}\w*", r"", text)
print(out)
>> I'm a really good     bb
```

So this RegEx will look for strings that have a repeating character of 3 repeats or more, even if it is in the beginning, middle, or end of the string.

something like 'bb' would could be captured by r"\s(.)\1{1,}\s"

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on sln's post, but I wanted to acknowledge that he covers all the use cases you have up there.

Question though: would there be any instances of something like eeeeerrrrr, where there are a few instances of repeating characters?

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be working fine. Is there a way to handle cases where we have one character of 2 repeats like rr, kk, qq, bb